# Video editing software for adding multilingual text

Tags: video, video-editing, voice-recording

[News Anchor](https://www.thebalancecareers.com/news-anchor-526047)

Is it possible to add multilingual content text in two different languages while editing a video?

Example : German, Russian, French news.

1 German news - The news content is displayed in German (Bottom) and English (Top).

2 Russian news - The news content is displayed in Russian (Bottom) and English (Top).

3 French news - The news content is displayed in French (Bottom) and English (Top).

Note : The voice of the speaker obviously is synchronized with the content shown in two languages (Top & Bottom).

Comment: You're speaking of subtitles? And of a) editing them or b) displaying them (so you look for an editor, or a player – because if a player can display them both, any subtitle editor would fit the bill)? Further, what OS must it run on, and how much you'd be willing to spend if it came to paid software? Also, what's the relation of the link to a job description here? It's about news, yes, but what's its importance for the software?

Comment: Thanks. You are right. Subtitles in multilingual text.

Comment: Thanks. I mean while viewing the news channel can there be multilingual text one for the news anchor in which he/she is reporting the language and other depending upon the other language which the news channel would like to display.

Comment: So you'd need 2 things: 1) a subtitle editor (they create one file per language usually) and 2) a video player allowing to show more than 1 language at the same time. Or you need to always place 2 lines in the same subtitle track – but then that cannot be split to show one line on top and the other on the bottom. Can you please **[edit]** your question and add that plus OS and pricing details?

Comment: Thanks. As you mention "but then that cannot be split to show one line on top and the other on the bottom.". This was my actual requirement. Why this is not possible? What are the technical limitations/hurdles/obstacles to accomplish this task?

Comment: Not sure. It probably would be technically possible – but I've never heard it's done. I'd rather imagine they'd go with 2 subtitle tracks (at least that's how I'd implement it, as otherwise you'd be restricted to fixed pairs). But then, I'm not a programmer in that field.

Comment: Thanks. CNN, BBC news, Al jajeera etc news channels.

Comment: What you will need is not a video editor, but a subtitle editor. I just saw something that seems to fit your description: https://easypronunciation.com/en/merge-two-subtitle-files-online (the screenshot has them split the way you described).

Comment: Thanks. So it is very much possible in CNN, BBC, Al jajeera, Wion  etc news channels when the news anchor is publishing news i.e Live ?

Comment: I have no idea of what CNN, BBC etc. are doing and how. As for "publishing live": someone must then provide the subtitles "live" as well, that's nothing you can do. In such a case it *might* be possible to use a voice transcript & automated translation, but that goes much beyond what I can (or would) handle.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Could this be achieved using voice transcript & automated translation?. The ideal keywords for this in google search engine could be voice transcript, automated translation?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=voice+transcript%2C+automation+translation&sxsrf=ALiCzsZchnMFhf4PIyJy4-VnyjUNG7BdSw%3A1659259816789&source=hp&ei=qEvmYrbVLZfChwONsZqoAw&oq=voice+transcript%2C+automation+translation&gs_lcp=ChFtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1ocBADMgUIIRCgATIFCCEQoAE6BwgjEOoCECc6BwguEOoCECc6BAgjECc6CAguELEDEIMBOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToLCC4QgAQQsQMQ1AI6BQgAEIAEOg4ILhCABBCxAxDHARDRAzoRCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQ0QM6CAgAEIAEELEDOgsILhCABBDHARCvAToGCAAQHhAWOggIABAeEA8QFjoFCAAQhgM6BwghEKABEAo6CAghEB4QFhAdUNIKWK_EAWDHzAFoAXAAeACAAcAEiAHPQJIBCjAuOC4yOC41LTGYAQCgAQGwAQ8&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-hp